# Autodesk forge viewer set toolbar button text without css

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a bunch of buttons I am adding to the toolbar in the viewer that I want text for instead of an icon. For the majority of cases I have been able to just add the text by setting content on the `.adsk-button-icon:before` which has worked perfectly although im not a huge fan of having the text set in the css file but it works.

I am now looking at adding buttons to the toolbar that will get the text when the viewer is loaded so I can not add the text via css beforehand.

Currently the only way I can see of doing this is creating the styles with JS or adding inline styles with JS which if possible I want to avoid. Is there a way to set a text (or better yet html) to the button or is there a control better suited for this.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/control/